# How to show highchart coloraxis min max value?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to set min and max values in ColorAxis property of highcharts.

what I really need is to show the min and max value passed instead of nearest rounded values.

```
colorAxis: [
      {         
        min: -2,
        max: 20,
        minColor:'#FF8900' ,
        maxColor:'#04BD24' ,
      },
```

Above code is generating values between "0" to "20"

[image: refer image attached]

I want output to be shown like "-2" as min and "20" as max in that bar. Please help!!

Comment: Have you already tried to define the `colorAxis.stops` to achieve it? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.stops

Comment: Tried it already but it only helped in showing different color. Number below that stack bar shows again min as "0" and max as "20". :(

Comment: May I see a reproduction of your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

`colorAxis: [{ min: -2, max: 20, minColor:'#FF8900', maxColor:'#04BD24', startOnTick:false, endOnTick:false, tickInterval: 0, }],`

Note that setting "**tickInterval**" to 0 along with setting "**startOnTick**" and "**endOnTick**" to false solves the issue